# Allow object of objects within inputs in action

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm wondering how I have objects of objects as inputs in an action - for example,

```
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Signup',

  description: 'Signup a user for an account.',

  inputs: {
    bride: {
        firstName: {
            description: 'The first name of the bride',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }
    },
    groom: {
        lastName: {
            description: 'The first name of the groom',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        }
    }
  }

  exits: {},

  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
      sails.log.debug(inputs.bride.firstName); // I would like to be able to reference input like this
      return exits.success();
  }
};
```

How can I do this and access inputs.bride.firstName (instead of having to do inputs.brideFirstName)?

I receive the following error trying to do this:

```
'Invalid input definition ("bride").  Must have `type`, or at least some more information.  (If you aren\'t sure what to use, just go with `type: \'ref\'.)' ] } }
```

Comment: In what context is `module.exports.fn` being called? PS: It seems like you're setting `module.exports.inputs.bride` twice, so the second declaration (`bride: ...`) is overriding the first.

Comment: This was just an example I made so I didn't have to copy the entire module, since most of it is out of context. Fixed the bride being declared twice. This is a SailsJS action, so it is being called by the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to implement a custom validation with objects of objects

```
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Signup',

  description: 'Signup a user for an account.',

  inputs: {
    bride: {
      description: 'The first name of the bride',
      type: 'json', // {'firstName': 'luis'}
      custom: function(value) {
        return _.isObject(value) && _.isString(value.firstName)
      }
    },
    groom: {
      description: 'The first name of the groom',
      type: 'json', // {'lastname': 'lazy'}
      custom: function(value) {
        return _.isObject(value) && _.isString(value.lastName)
      }
    }
  }

  exits: {},

  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
      sails.log.debug(inputs.bride.firstName); // luis
      return exits.success();
  }
};
```

More information on: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations#?custom-validation-rules

Comment: This seems like the best option. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, for example query language apply to actions

Comment: Thanks @LuisReinoso that is super interesting. Is it possible to return a custom validation message on failure, instead of just returning false? Returning false gives the default message of `problems: ['Invalid "fields":\n  · Value failed custom validation.']`

Comment: Please visit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047831/exits-custom-sails-1-and-actions-2

Answer (score 0):

You should use a json type for this case. Sails don't check attributes in json type.

```
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Signup',

  description: 'Signup a user for an account.',

  inputs: {
    bride: {
      description: 'The first name of the bride',
      type: 'json', // {'firstName': 'luis'}
      required: true
    },
    groom: {
      description: 'The first name of the groom',
      type: 'json', // {'lastname': 'lazy'}
      required: true        
    }
  }

  exits: {},

  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
      sails.log.debug(inputs.bride.firstName); // luis
      return exits.success();
  }
};
```

More info about types: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes#?type

Comment: That would work but it wouldn't allow me to apply validation rules to the child properties of bride or groom.

Comment: Should this post be deleted? Isn't your accepted solution a copy of this, but with the extra addition of validation?